# SelectOneMenu seems to mutate the values in the backing bean list

Tags: java, jsf, selectonemenu

I am using Primefaces 3.2 on Myfaces 2.0.2 using glassfish 3.1.2. I have tested in both firefox 14.0.1 and safari 5.1.7 and receive the same behavior in both. When I select a value that is not the first in the list in the dropdown, and click the command button, it appears that the selected item replaces the first element in the list (see sample output below).

Am I not supposed to use a straight list in my bean to back a selectOneMenu? Or am I doing something else wrong?

I have created a simple test case that reproduces the issue below:

```java
package com.example;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    private List<ContainerObject> container;
    private ContainerObject selectedContainerObject;

    public TestBean()
    {
        container= new ArrayList<ContainerObject>();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize()
    {
        container.add(new ContainerObject("String 1"));
        container.add(new ContainerObject("String 2"));
        container.add(new ContainerObject("String 3"));
        container.add(new ContainerObject("String 4"));
        container.add(new ContainerObject("String 5"));
        selectedContainerObject = container.get(0);
    }

    public List<ContainerObject> getContainer()
    {
        return container;
    }

    public ContainerObject getSelectedContainerObject()
    {
        return selectedContainerObject;
    }

    public void listContainer(ActionEvent event)
    {
        for(ContainerObject c : container)
            System.out.println(c.getValue());
    }

    public class ContainerObject
    {
        String value;

        public ContainerObject(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }   
}
```

The following is my xhtml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<h:html
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="container" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="c" value="#{testBean.selectedContainerObject.value}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.container}" var="container" 
                    itemLabel="#{container.value}" itemValue="#{container.value}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="submit list" 
                actionListener="#{testBean.listContainer}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</h:html>
```

The following is what gets printed out to the console as a result of choosing "String 3" and pressing the submit button.

```
INFO: String 3
INFO: String 2
INFO: String 3
INFO: String 4
INFO: String 5
```

But I expected to see

```
INFO: String 1
INFO: String 2
INFO: String 3
INFO: String 4
INFO: String 5
```

I also get the same behavior when I use h:selectOneMenu as I do when I use p:selectOneMenu.

Comment: I'd suggest going through a basic Java tutorial once again. Java is an object oriented language where you pass around object references (memory pointers), not a procedural language where you pass around copied values, like PHP or something.

Comment: I replaced container.get(0) with new ContainerObject("String 3") and that did fix the issue. To be explicit, the selectedObject's setter is called with the new value. Since in this case, the reference is to the same object as what is in the list, it modifies the list item as well. The lesson here is the selectedObject should always be a copy, and not a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selectedContainerObject = container.get(0);
```

I think this is where you're going wrong, you're effectively setting the value property of the selectOne object to the 1st element of the list itself, so whatever you select will end up in the first element of the list.

Comment: In other words, to fix this problem, he needs `selectedContainerObject = new ContainerObject("String 1");`, provided that the `equals()` method of that class is properly implemented.